# How to generate tile based natural looking map?

Tags: maps, tiles

I have a tile based map which I generate using interpolation of pixels on a reference bitmap into appropriate tiles depending on the color of the pixel.

[image]

I'm trying to make the output look natural in which blocks of similar tiles look like they are forming a single entity as in the following image:

[image]

While my version only puts static sprites onto aligned cells, the second image  takes forest tiles and smashes them together like a whole single forest.
The same is done for the water area.

Could someone explain or point me somewhere where I can learn how to make the result of the first image look like the second? Thank you

Also, how are the seamless road connections done in the above image?

Comment: I don't quite understand, which image shows your current result and which shows the result you want?

Comment: @Bálint The first is mine, the second is the result I want.

Comment: If you're looking for tips on how to make tiles that join seamlessly edge-to-edge, you might find this previous question useful: [Making Edges of Hand-Drawn Tileset Match Up](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/112764/making-edges-of-hand-drawn-tileset-match-up). There are [many types of tiling pattern](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/148464/39518) you can use, depending on how many variations you want to create.

Comment: @DMGregory if i'm reading this right, he's asking about how to get the tiles to spawn grouped together by type, not just randomly distributed